# Is it possible to detect WebRTC one-to-one audio or video call duration in Node?

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I am very new to webrtc, I am slightly confused about it.

I am able to do one-to-one video/audio call using node.js, but still confused is it possible to check how long two people had talked?

If yes, please guide me.

If not then what is the best way to monitor call length? (I don't want to record audio or video, just the length).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using nodejs as your socket server, or as the actual endpoints?  Last I checked webrtc didn't have a native nodejs interface but you could use one of the available NPM modules.

It's always possible to track from the app side.  Get the time at the start, get the time at the end and report that to your server.  The WebRTC api for iOS, Android, and JS has a GetStats api you can call during or after a session to get this information as well.  AppRTC has examples on how to do that.